# Запрос к MySQL для выборки данных, совпадающих с данными в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, mysqli

День добрый, уважаемые участники!
Надеюсь на помощь коммьюнити.

Итак, имеем две таблицы:

Tabl№1

```
| Ads | Date  |
| :--------- | :-------------- |
| Куплю пшеницу    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Нужен камаз    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Нужен рукав    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Ищу станок    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
```

Tabl№2

```
| Zag |
| :--------- |
| пшениц    |
| Камаз    |
```

Как прописать запрос к таблице №1 MySQL, чтобы получить лишь те данные, которые соответствуют условию:

1. Чтобы брались лишь те строки из столбца 'Ads' Tabl№1, которые совпадают с данными из столбца 'Zag' из таблицы Tabl№2

На итоге должен получить лишь такие данные из Tabl№1:

```
| Ads | Date  |
| :--------- | :-------------- |
| Куплю пшеницу    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Нужен камаз    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
```

Делаю так, но не срабатывает:((((

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
SELECT *
FROM `Tabl№1`
WHERE `Ads` LIKE (SELECT st.`Zag` FROM `Tabl№2` as st)
```

Очень надеюсь на поддержку сообщества, ибо не знаю как правильно прописать.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON LOCATE(t2.zag, t1.ads)```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Единственный вопрос - этот параметр будет доп. условием. Как его правильно прописать?
Т.е. сначала идет условия 
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
SELECT *
FROM `Tabl№1`
WHERE (`Date` REGEXP '^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$'
OR LOWER(`Date`) LIKE "%сегодня%")

А как в конце правильно прописать Ваш предложенные вариант?